# How to ignore user input on Python while threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I just wrote this simple code.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

counter=0
input_var=0

class inputprogram:  
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True

    def terminate(self):  
        self._running = False  

    def take(self):
        global input_var
        while self._running:
            time.sleep(1) 
            input_var = input("Enter something: ")

avaliable= inputprogram()
avaliableinput = Thread(target=avaliable.take)
avaliableinput.start()




while input_var!= 'exit': 

    counter=counter+1
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print (counter)



avaliable.terminate()
```

I execute this code in RPi. I want my counter to not stop while user enters input or enters nothing. What it does is waiting on threads before continue. Is there any user input method to resolve this issue? Or should I try something else?

Comment: I would say that the counter does not stop. What you do see?

Comment: It stops when counter reaches 4 until user enters input then countines to 9 then stops again.... and goes on.

Comment: The counter never stops for me...

Comment: I am exetucing this on Raspberry Pi 2.  Can there be any problem because of this?

Comment: The problem is solved when I use terminal but works problematic on IDLE(python ide on RPi) screen.

Comment: @Bcan, please copy your last comment with the solution to an answer below and accept it.  This removes this question from the unanswered list.

Comment: or you can remove your question.

Comment: I can't accept it for first 2 days. It can help someone one day so better leave it here I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Run->Run Module** from IDLE editor screen or

```
exec(open('filename.py').read())
```

from IDLE Shell doesn't work as intended.

To solve this problem, execute the .py file on terminal with :
(if python3 used)

```
python3 filename.py
```